# Swift 3 Core Data NSInternalInconsistencyException entityForName could not locate an entity named Foo in this model

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, ios-frameworks

I have a framework project and getting that strange error when I try to unit test my classes. 
here is code suggested by [Andrew Bancroft](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/01/13/unit-testing-model-layer-core-data-swift/) to get in memory`NSManagedObjectContext`

```
func setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])!
    let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

    do {
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Adding in-memory persistent store failed")
    }

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

    return managedObjectContext
}
```

But whenever I try to insert an object (or any other db operation) by this code

```
 let newLocationMO = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: table, into: context) as! LocationMO
```

It crashes with error mentioned in title.

I also tried to test with real context, so I import my framework to a temporary project and get context from AppDelegate auto-generated code but it crashes with same error as if it doesn't see my `.xcdatamodeld` definition.

Note: I checked all typos and that no file is missing.

Maybe it is not allowed to have Core Data in framework project ?
Any links or example of core data usage in framework project is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Core Data in a framework but you need to make sure that your code knows that it's in a framework. The most likely source of trouble is this line:

```
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])!
```

If you're in a framework, your model is not in the main bundle. You're telling it to look in the wrong place, so it's not finding the model file.

You probably want to change that to `Bundle(for: type(of:self))` so that you'll be looking in the same bundle that contains the framework classes.

Comment: Thanks for answer Tom, looks that it solves the problem with context creation but now there is another problem. It says: CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'MyFramework.MyClass' for entity 'MyClass'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_MyClass_' to 'MyFramework.MyClass' any idea why ? MyClass is auto-generated public class

Comment: ok after many attempts of doing same thing i.e. remove xcdatamodeld module then recreating classes it started working in test. but still cannot use my framework inside of real project looks like it doesn't see xcdatamodeld.